# .htaccess subdomain redirect bug

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

**Question**

Would appreciate insight to how the `.htaccess` be modified to solve the problem detailed below.

---

**Background**

A support site is hosted at `support.domain.com`. It is desired to have following behaviours

- `https://support.domain.com` remains `https://support.domain.com`
- `http://support.domain.com` redirects to `https://support.domain.com`
- `http://domain.com/support` redirects to `https://support.domain.com`
- `http://www.domain.com/support` redirects to `https://support.domain.com`
- `https://domain.com/support` redirects to `https://support.domain.com`
- `https://www.domain.com/support` redirects to `https://support.domain.com`

Problem is that following behaviour are observed.

- `https://support.domain.com` redirects to `https://www.domain.com` [ERROR]
- `http://support.domain.com` redirects to `https://www.domain.com` [ERROR]
- `http://domain.com/support` redirects to `https://www.domain.com` [ERROR]
- `http://www.domain.com/support` redirects to `https://www.domain.com` [ERROR]
- `https://domain.com/support` redirects to `https://domain.com/support/` (expected page for - `support.domain.com`) [GOOD]
- `https://www.domain.com/support` redirects to `https://www.domain.com/support/` (expected page `support.domain.com`) [GOOD]

The current live `.htaccess` rule are:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
# End Enforce https

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#
#Domain re-direction
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainnet\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainnet\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com [L,NE,R=301]
#
#Support page re-direction
RewriteRule ^justsupport/?$ https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/forsupport\/ [L,NE,R=301]
</ifModule>
```

---

**Solution**

I used solution suggested by @anubhava.
I modified that solution as it did not work perfectly for `http://support.domain.com`.
Below is the full updated solution and script that now works.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# Enforce https 
# “IfModule” is not used as we want web-server to give error if “mod_rewrite.c” missing
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/?support/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(support\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
# End Enforce https

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#
#Domain re-direction
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainnet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
#end domain re-direction

#Support page
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://support.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^support/?$ https://support.domain.com/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]
#end Support page

#web support page re-direction
RewriteRule ^justsupport/?$ https://www.domain.com/forsupport/ [L,NE,NC,R=301]
#end web support page re-direction
</ifModule>
```

---

**Result**

Below is evidence that the modified solution works as desired.

- `http://support.domain.com` now redirects to `https://support.domain.com`     [GOOD]
- `https://support.domain.com` is `https://support.domain.com` as expected      [GOOD]
- `https://domain.com/support` now redirects to `https://support.domain.com`        [GOOD]
- `http://domain.com/support` now redirects to `https://support.domain.com`     [GOOD]
- `https://www.domain.com/support` now redirects to `https://support.domain.com`    [GOOD]
- `http://www.domain.com/support` now redirects to `https://support.domain.com`     [GOOD]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# Enforce https 
# “IfModule” is not used as we want web-server to give error if “mod_rewrite.c” missing
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/?support/?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(support\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
# End Enforce https

#Domain re-direction
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainnet\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
#end domain re-direction

#Support page
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^support\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://support.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^support/?$ https://support.domain.com/ [L,NC,NE,R=301]
#end Support page

#web support page re-direction
RewriteRule ^justsupport/?$ https://www.domain.com/forsupport/ [L,NE,NC,R=301]
#end web support page re-direction
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava. Your solution did not initially work perfectly. It was slightly modified to make it work for my use-case. The modification now works.

Comment: Does it matter if we update your own script with the modified version (placed under "Solution" in the original question). Or is it best to just leave it as they are ...